# Chrome Extension component communication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that has 3 components that do the following:

1. Popup script - in the document ready function utilizes native messaging to get an ENV variable (user id).  So now I have this value in a variable here, but I need the value in the Background scrpit
2. Content script adds code to the target page, and when a certain event occurs, gets data from that page and passes it to the background script - this works fine.
3. Background script - gets the payload from the content scprit, and makes an HTTP call with it - this works fine.

The problem I am having is in one "flavor" of this extension, I need to get that User ID from the popup script to the background script, as it becomes part of the URL I need to invoke.  I need to basically construct 'http://URLBase/UserId/suffix' in the background script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to set and retrieve values available to all your scripts.

For things like user settings you can add an [options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) rather than your browser action popup.